# NewEventDTO is not a valid Event Type

Tags: events, nethereum

The solidity code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
event NewEvent(uint32 tag, uint32 idx);
```

My Nethereum code

```
public class NewEventDTO
{
    [Parameter("uint32", "tag", 1, false)]
    public uint Tag { get; set; }

    [Parameter("uint32", "idx", 2, false)]
    public uint Index{ get; set; }
}

var w = new Web3(mNodeUrl);
var c = w.Eth.GetContract(mAbi, mAdd);
var eNew = c.GetEvent("NewEvent");
var fNew = eNew.CreateFilterAsync().Result;

var en = eNew.GetFilterChanges<NewEventDTO>(fNew).Result; // ** Error
```

There is no reason for the code above to fail. But it kept on complaining **"NewEventDTO is not a valid Event Type"**

Hope someone can shed some light in this issue.

Is there any changes in Nethereum where I need to derive my DTO from a specific class?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer myself after downloading Nethereum source code and trying to debug myself.

The latest version requires us to put the [Event()] attribute for Event DTO